# synchronized block with different class as lock

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I want to know if my understanding of `synchronized(x.class){..}` is correct.

**Assumption:**

1. I have two variables within a class which will be initialized, if needed. But only once.
2. I want to block multiple access to each variable from different threads.
3. I only want to block variable wise and not to the complete SingletonExample instance.

**Example:**

```
public class SingletonExample{

    private volatile SingletonA var;
    private volatile SingletonB tar;

    public void initVarOnDemand1() {
        if (var == null) {
            synchronized (SingletonA.class) {
                if (var == null) {
                    var = SingletonA.getInstance(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initVarOnDemand2() {
        if (var == null) {
            synchronized (SingletonA.class) {
                if (var == null) {
                    var = SingletonA.getInstance(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initTarOnDemand1() {
        if (tar == null) {
            synchronized (SingletonB.class) {
                if (tar == null) {
                    tar = new SingletonB.getInstance(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initTarOnDemand2() {
        if (tar == null) {
            synchronized (SingletonB.class) {
                if (tar == null) {
                    tar = SingletonB.getInstance(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My final goal is, that no two threads can simultaneously change variable `var` and no two threads can change simultaneously variable `tar`.

**But I do not want to block two threads, that access different variables.**

Therefore I use block synchronization with each class as the lock object.

**Is this the correct way for what I want?** (I hope I explained it well enough - sorry for my bad english).

Comment: Do you want exclusive access to `var` across all instances of YourClass, or just the current instance?

Comment: The wrapping class in the example...let's say Example.class is a singleton itself. And it will initialize var and tar, which are singletons too. But I want the initialization to be atomic and on demand.

Comment: There is nothing you can do in Java to prevent different threads from accessing a variable. The only thing you can prevent with `synchronized` is, you can prevent different threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time. If you don't want different threads to access certain data at the same time, then it's up to you to structure your code such that no thread ever accesses the data except when inside a `synchronized(o)` block for some unique object, `o`.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to this would be to use `AtomicReference.compareAndSet`:

```
private final AtomicReference<Integer> var = new AtomicReference<>();

public void foo() {
  var.compareAndSet(null, 1);
}

public void bar() {
  var.compareAndSet(null, -1);
}
```

This only sets the value of `var` if its current value is equal to the first parameter (in this case `null`).

Comment: Thank you for the answer so far, I'll edit the question to make it more clear.